# Nodemon resarts nodes server when writing a json file

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, nodes, nodemon

My node server restarts every time when I write a json file using fs.writeFileSync().
How can I configure nodemon to ignore all json files in my project?

I tried adding nodemon.json file in root of my folder

```
{
"ignore": ["*.json"]
}
```

I tried also adding following code in package.json

```
..
"nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": [
      "*.json"
    ]
}
```

Also tried to specify in nodemonConfig to ignore whole folder where I have json files "src/config/"

Comment: try to provide the config file to nodemon during the start command, like nodemon app.js --config nodemon.json ( https://github.com/remy/nodemon )

Comment: Great! Now it works, thanks. I only made a config file but didn't provide it to a command, stupid me...